# Google app engine CNAME redirection

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an application which is running on GAE. I would like to use a custom URL and 
have configured the cname as per the instructions on google. But end up getting an SSL error even though the cname look up works fine. I am wondering if there's any special setting i need to enable on the GAE side?

*

```
Find the CNAME settings and enter the following as the CNAME value or alias: 
status
Set the CNAME destination to the following address: 
ghs.googlehosted.com
```

*

The specific error I am getting back is:
Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.

Comment: You know that you need to supply an ssl-certificate for *your* domain to the appengine if you want ssl on a custom domain?

Comment: Yep, That was the issue. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl

Comment: what if you **DO NOT WANT** SSL and it is doing this redirect anyway, how do you stop it?